# How to fix compatibility between libraries

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework-jwt

I;m trying to perform some actions with jwt token. I'm working with Django-rest-jwt, which requires PyJWT and jwt. The problem is - I made fork to PyJWT cause I need some code working another way, and when I try to use Django-rest-jwt, it says that he can't find jwt, also pip3 gives me this, when I install my fork.

[image: pic]

btw fork works correctly. So, how can I make Django-rest-jwt use my fork instead of PyJWT? I tried to fork it and change requirements, but didn't find PyJWT at all

Comment: The issue is in the versions and not the fact that it is a fork. So if you absolutely need your fork then upgrade djangorestframework-jwt to a version that accepts >2.0.0 of PyJWT

Comment: Images of error text like error messages should be augmented with the text that the image contains, or replaced by it. This is because images are not searchable, or accessible, and on small screens nearly impossible to read.

Answer (score 0):

Use lower version of `PyJWT`, like 1.7.1:
`pip install pyjwt==1.7.1`

or if you are using `requirements.txt` file, change you pyjwt version there.